# Screenshot capturing from wayback machine using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am capturing screenshots of Wayback machine urls using the python chrome driver using this code

```
df_merged_new_url  = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ='./chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get(row["new_url"])
time.sleep(15)
 
driver.save_screenshot(screen_path)
```

Now this code is capturing screenshots with buffered spaces on the left and right
[image]

My desired screenshot should more look like how it would look to the viewer if that webpage were live, like below:-

[image]

Here is some sample urls for webpages:
https://web.archive.org/web/20080221233711/http://www.berkshire.com/

https://web.archive.org/web/20171107004101/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/

https://web.archive.org/web/20200224044229/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can take screenshots of a specific web element instead of taking screenshots of the page itself.

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common import NoAlertPresentException

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument("force-device-scale-factor=0.95")

driver = Chrome(options=options)

urls = ['https://web.archive.org/web/20080221233711/http://www.berkshire.com/',
        'https://web.archive.org/web/20171107004101/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/',
        'https://web.archive.org/web/20200224044229/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/']

for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    if url.endswith('www.berkshire.com/'):
        target_element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
        target_element.screenshot(f'{i}_screen_capture.png')
        
    elif url.endswith('www.berkshirefunds.com/'):
        try:
           driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
        except NoAlertPresentException:
            pass
        target_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#page-wrap')
        target_element.screenshot(f'{i}_screen_capture.png')
```

output:
`0_screen_capture.png`

[image]

`1_screen_capture.png`

[image]

`2_screen_capture.png`

[image]

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Hey, there are multiple urls which need to be screenshot, am not sure every URL has <tbody> component 
for eg: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20171107004101/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/

https://web.archive.org/web/20200224044229/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/

Comment: different URLs may have different UI (different web elements, layouts). But if the URLs are different with the same layout or domains as the two you mentioned then you can use the same element to take screenshots otherwise if there's not much variation in the URLs then you can put a check in place before taking the screenshot.

Comment: Could you add that check component in code? not exactly sure what you meant there

Comment: I've edited the code above

Answer (score 0):

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and try the following.

Also, note that I recommend using Firefox over Chrome for complete page screenshots. Firefox has a built-in feature for this that other browsers lack (this may have changed since I checked it last).

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserType, BrowserSettings
from pathlib import Path

browser_settings = BrowserSettings(
    type=BrowserType.FIREFOX,
    headless=True,
    screenshot_dir=Path("/your/screenshots/folder")
)

with Browser(browser_settings) as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://web.archive.org/web/20080221233711/http://www.berkshire.com/")
    browser.screenshot.complete_page()
    browser.screenshot.element("/html/body/table/tbody")
```

Notes:

- You don't need to maximise the browser screen. As viewport size depends on the monitor – imagine how large a screenshot of 42" screen would be – you may end up with a large image with too much whitespace. It's better to use the default browser size for this purpose, but you can maximise the window size with `browser.window.maximize()` before you take screenshots if needed (not added to the example above).
- Update the `screenshot_dir=Path("/your/screenshots/folder")` setting to what your destination folder should be.
- The `browser.screenshot.complete_page()` command is generic and takes a screenshot of the full page.
- The `browser.screenshot.element("/html/body/table/tbody")` command targets the body of the Berkshire.com site, but probably can't be reused for other sites.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit timers like `time.sleep(15)` – this will slow down your code significantly or make the script break when it's too short. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://github.com/jakob-bagterp/browserist#improved-stability-and-less-code).

The `browser.screenshot.element("/html/body/table/tbody")` command yields this:

[image: Berkshire.com screenshot of body content only]

The `browser.screenshot.complete_page()` command yields this:

[image: Berkshire.com complete page screenshot]

I hope you find it useful. Let me know if you have any questions?

EDIT: To scale the above example to multiple sites, here's an option to pair URLs with XPath for the body element. As far as I can see, it's not possible to make a generic XPath that targets the site body so you would need a little manual work for each page. I hope it helps:

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserType, BrowserSettings
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path

browser_settings = BrowserSettings(
    type=BrowserType.FIREFOX,
    headless=True,
    screenshot_dir=Path("/your/screenshots/folder")
)

@dataclass()
class Archive():
    url: str
    body_xpath: str

archives = [
    Archive("https://web.archive.org/web/20080221233711/http://www.berkshire.com/", "/html/body/table/tbody"),
    Archive("https://example.com", "/xpath/to/body/element"),
]

with Browser(browser_settings) as browser:
    for archive in archives:
        browser.open.url(archive.url)
        browser.screenshot.element(archive.body_xpath)
```

Comment: Thanks for response, there are multiple urls which need to be screenshot, am not sure every url has tbody component 
for eg: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20171107004101/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/

https://web.archive.org/web/20200224044229/http://www.berkshirefunds.com/

Comment: Also, can we use Browserlist in headless mode? as i am running the script on linux

Comment: True. As mentioned above, you'll need to adapt the screenshot element to the relevant XPath element of each URL. For instance, how about creating a list of pairs of URL and XPath so you can iterate over them? I'll update the code example above so you can scale it.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate a piece of code by which I can identify the component of each URL which need to be used in Selenium driver code to scrape the correct part from the webpage

Comment: You're welcome. Please check the extended example above. Again, it doesn't seem possible to guess the XPath of the body element of each page. A little manual work would be needed.

Comment: Regarding your question about headless mode: Yes. That's why I added the `headless=True` part to the `BrowserSettings `.